# How does Rails.application.configure block works without providing a variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, it's common to see a pattern like this (in `config/environments/development.rb` for example):

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.some_option = some_value

end
```

I was intrigued by this idiom since I was recently researching how these configure `blocks` work and ended up discovering [this very similar pattern](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block), where the `configure` method initializes an (generally memoized) instance of a configuration Class (that has the accessors for the configuration options) and yield that instance object to the block. Something like this:

```
module Clearance
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :mailer_sender

    def initialize
      @mailer_sender = 'donotreply@example.com'
    end
  end
end
```

That's why `Clearance.configure {|config| config.mailer_sender = 'something'}` works, because it's yielding that instance of Configuration class to the block variable `config`.

But the way Rails does it, there's no variable being passed to that block. There's no `Rails.application.configure do |config|` so the block can change the configuration object accessors. I thought `config` would be undefined inside that block, but it isn't.

Tried looking at rails source code and I suspect it has to do with the [configurable module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5ccdd0bb6d1262a670645ddf3a9e334be4545dac/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb), but I couldn't 100% understand the code I found there.

Comment: I'm tagging this Ruby as well as it seems to have much more to do with ruby then with the framework itself.

Comment: It is actually the framework. The framework defined the `delegate` method that enable this capability.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `Configurable` module isn't used by the actual Rails railtie.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5ccdd0bb6d1262a670645ddf3a9e334be4545dac/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb#L170

I don't claim to understand it's usage fully, but apparently the `delegate` method [used in `Railtie` class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5ccdd0bb6d1262a670645ddf3a9e334be4545dac/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb#L127)

```
delegate :config, to: :instance
```

adds a `config` attribute pointing to an instance of `Rails::Application::Configuration` - the one which we later access through `Rails.application.config`.

https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: This gave me better understanding. If anyone want to see the implementation of the [delegate method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5ccdd0bb6d1262a670645ddf3a9e334be4545dac/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L157)

Answer (score 0):

It uses [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) (or `class_eval` which does essentially the same) to evaluate the block in the context of a specified object. Within the block, that object becomes the implicit receiver (i.e. `self`).

For example, using your code:

```
module Clearance
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure(&block)
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    configuration.instance_eval(&block)
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :mailer_sender

    def initialize
      @mailer_sender = 'donotreply@example.com'
    end
  end
end

Clearance.configure { self.mailer_sender = 'something' }

Clearance.configuration.mailer_sender #=> "something"
```

Comment: but there's no implicit receiver, there's `config` as receiver

Comment: @sandre89 yes and no. If you have `config.some_option = some_value` then `config` is the receiver for `some_option` (or `:some_option=`), but `self` is the receiver for `config`.